# Incoming Call Screen obstruction by an Activity (Theme Dialog) over it

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I am trying to show an Activity (with Theme Dialog) over an Incoming call Screen to show some information. I am done with the that, but the problem is whenever the call comes, Activity Dialog pops up over it and it covers SLIDER ( for accepting/Rejecting calls) .

I want the Activity Dialog over Incoming call screen but still wants the user to pick/reject calls.

I did use this But now unable to finish activity(Dialog).

> getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
>               getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);

Warm Regards

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);   

getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
        setContentView(R.layout.notedialog);
        this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
        initializeContent();

        phone_no = getIntent().getExtras().getString("phone_no");
        String note  = getIntent().getExtras().getString("note");

        tv_client.setText(phone_no + " is calling you");
        note_mEditText.setText(note);

        dialog_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity.this.finish();
           //        this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you show me some code ?

Comment: Please check Question Sir. @Ashu

Comment: ah it is android question , sorry i am not developer of android :)

Comment: Its Okay sir. ThanQ btw.

Comment: So you have an overlapped activity dialog with your SLIDER..And what you want is to move its position right ?

Comment: Yes Sir, and if i use 'getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE); getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);' unable to dismiss that dialog.  @sunil

Comment: Can you try using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog` for this actvity..and get rid off all those getWindow() codes..

Comment: @sunilsunny No Sir Its Not working. It override the call pickup buttons.

Comment: First of all why are you using an Activity dialog ? You can use a simple dialog right ..I will give an exmple..

Comment: If im using this **android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"** Its shows perfect at top of screen, But same issue I can't receive or decline call util i don't dismiss dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for an Activity with dialog style.
Call this method only when you want to show the dialog.
This will create a dialog on top of your phone.

```
final Dialog dialog;
public void showDialog(){
  dialog = new Dialog(this,
            android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);

    // Setting dialogview
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);

    window.setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    dialog.setTitle(null);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.notedialog);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    dialog.show();
    }
```

And to cancel the dialog call this method.

```
public void cancelDialog(){
if(dialog!= null ){
dialog.dismiss()
}
}
```

**OR**

If you insist to use an Activity dialog You can use this method to change the position of window.

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    View view = getWindow().getDecorView();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.TOP
    lp.x = 10;
    lp.y = 10;
    lp.width = 300;
    lp.height = 300;
    getWindowManager().updateViewLayout(view, lp);
}
```

Comment: It crashes on **dialog.show();**  `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application`